# Convolution Layer output changes to 1. after passing it through a fully connected layer for every image

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, conv-neural-network

I built a CNN using theano. The code for the Convolution and Hidden layers is:

```
class HiddenLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self,n_in,n_out,inp_vector=T.dmatrix(),non_linearity='sigmoid',W=None,b=None):
        Layer.__init__(self,n_in,n_out,W,b)
        self.inp=inp_vector
        out=self.non_lins[non_linearity](inp_vector.dot(self.W.transpose())+self.b)
        self.output=out

class ConvolutionLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self,W_shape,b_shape,image_shape,inp_vector=T.tensor4(),maxpool=(2,2),non_linearity='tanh',W=None,b=None,flatten=False,batch=1):
        W=theano.shared(numpy.random.standard_normal(W_shape))
        b=theano.shared(numpy.random.random(b_shape))
        Layer.__init__(self,0,0,W,b)
        self.inp=inp_vector
        out=convop.conv2d(input=inp_vector,filters=self.W,filter_shape=W_shape,image_shape=image_shape)
        self.output=self.non_lins[non_linearity](downsample.max_pool_2d(out,maxpool,ignore_border=True)+self.b.dimshuffle('x',0,'x','x'))
        if flatten:
            self.output=self.output.flatten(batch)
        else:
            self.output=self.output
```

My neural network has 5 layers. But for checking what was going wrong, I stripped off all the other hidden layers and just kept the one which is connected to the convolution layer. I observed that the output of the convolution layer was fine, but after passing it through the fully connected layer, it became:

```
(2, 5000)
[[-1. -1. -1. ..., -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. ..., -1. -1. -1.]]
```

here 2,5000 is the shape of the output matrix of the hidden layer. The network implementation is:

```
layer0=machinebrain.ConvolutionLayer(image_shape=(2,3,480,640),W_shape=
(2,3,5,5),maxpool=(4,4),b_shape=(2,))
layer1=machinebrain.ConvolutionLayer(image_shape=(2,2,119,159),inp_vector=
layer0.output,maxpool=(2,2),W_shape=(3,2,5,5),b_shape=(3,),flatten=True,batch=2)
layer3=machinebrain.HiddenLayer(inp_vector=layer1.output,
non_linearity='tanh',n_in=13167,n_out=5000)
```

Any idea what might be causing the output of convolution layers to change to all 1.'s after passing through the hidden layer?

Answer (score 1):

Your nonlinearity is tanh which has saturating values of -1 (corresponding to a very negative input) and +1 (corresponding to a very large positive input). Perhaps the activations of your layers are giving you very large values in magnitude? You can try global contrast normalization to your input (zero center and divide by the standard deviation) to better condition your input values. Also try switching to a ReLU activation or even linear activation to check what sort of activations values you are getting from the particular layer you are referencing.

Comment: Figured it out. It was not the inputs. I had used random initialized weights. So for very large number of neurons, the dot product between the activation of previous layer and the weights of the current layer used to saturate the tanh. Tried Glorot uniform weight initialization. Works fine now,

Comment: Oh good catch. I usually use Lasagne or some other framework build on top of Theano and they usually have good weight initialization by default. But it's good to remember how important weight initialization is.